# Have trouble displaying image in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, pixel

So I've tried to write some pixels using MemoryImageSource and display it in a frame. Here's the code:

```
public class ImageDraw extends JPanel {

Image img;

public void ImageDraw(){        
    //super();      
    int w=600;
    int h=400;

    int pixels[] = new int[w*h];    
    int i=0;    
    for(i=0;i<w*h;i++){
        //pixels[i++]=0;
        pixels[i]=255;      
    }   
    img = createImage(new MemoryImageSource(w,h,pixels,0,w));
}

 public void paint(Graphics g){     
    g.drawImage(img,  0, 0, this);
 }
}
```

and the main code

```
public class FuncTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);

    ImageDraw pan = new ImageDraw();
    frame.getContentPane().add(pan);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

It just displays an empty frame. Why? My aim is to learn how to draw pixel by pixel, so this is only a test image I was drawing to see whether it works.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? It looks like you're making a blank image and painting it on a blank panel...an empty panel is what I'd expect.

Comment: I was expecting a background of one color, didn't really care which color since I was just attending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First

```
public void ImageDraw() {  ... }
```

is a method and not the constructor. The method is not called in your code at all. Change this line to

```
public ImageDraw() {  ... }
```

without the `void` to make it the default constructor.

Second you need to set the alpha-value of your pixel data:

```
pixels[i] = 255 + 0xFF000000;
```

And two more points:

- Please do not override `paint(...)` but `paintComponent(...)` instead.
- Do not set the size of the `JFrame` but override the component's method `getPreferredSize()` and use `frame.pack()`.

Comment: Good catch on the constructor, but how then is he not getting a NPE when he runs his code? `img` should be null in the `paint` method.

Comment: @Paul `drawImage` has a `null` check included.

Comment: Oh thanks! What's the structure of the pixel data? Is it RGBA by default? Can I specify a different model?

Comment: +1, @Achint, did you read the MemoryImageSource API to see what the valid constructors and methods are?

Comment: @Achint you could create a `DirectColorModel` using the 4 arg constructor specifying 24 bits and masks of `0xff0000` for red, `0x00ff00` for green, and `0x0000ff` for blue. That will treat all pixels as opaque.

Comment: Yeah, I made the mistake of thinking when I didn't specify it would take RGB. I was following a tutorial for this, I'll go through the API documentation.

Comment: @Paul, Ok thanks, I'll try that. I can then use the DirectColorModel object as the argument in MemoryImageConstructor and specify the model, right?

Comment: @Achint, yes, most of the constructors for `MemoryImageSource` take a `ColorModel`, and there is one very similar to the one you used above.